# Microsoft Access Form with multiselect listbox

Tags: ms-access-2010, listboxitem

I have a form in Microsoft Access which has a combobox which contains counties. Based on the selection of county there is a listbox which will show the amounts that are realted to that county. When I select a amount from listbox and click on find button then it will generate two subforms, one subform shows the lowest prices for line items present in that amount with query:

```
SELECT Data.Item, Min(Data.[Unit Price]) AS Minimum
FROM Data
WHERE (((Data.[Bid Amount])=Forms![Report]![List2]))
GROUP BY Data.Item;
```

and the other subform shows the average prices for line items presnt in that amount  with query:

```
SELECT Data.Item, Avg(Data.[Unit Price]) AS Average
FROM Data
WHERE (((Data.[Bid Amount])=[Forms]![Report]![List2]))
GROUP BY Data.Item;
```

Right now selecting a single amount from list box works fine but if I need to multi select the amounts from listbox then what code I need to write in Find button? I tried using code below but it is not working.

```
Dim varItem As Variant
Dim strFind As String
Dim Task As String

For Each varItem In Me!List2.itemselected
    strFind = srtFind & "," & Me!List2.ItemData(varItem)
Next varItem
If Len(strFind) = 0 Then
    Task = "Select Amount(s)"
Else
    strFind = Right(strFind, Len(strFind) - 1)
    Task = "select * from Data where ([Bid Amount] in (" & strFind & "))"
End If
DoCmd.ApplyFilter Task
```

Also, I am attaching a screenshot of my form if it helps.
[Access Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SO9Zs.png)

Answer (score 1):

A filter is only the where clause and, I guess, it is the subforms you wish to filter, so try something like this:

```vb
Dim varItem     As Variant
Dim strFind     As String
Dim Filter      As String
Dim FilterOn    As Boolean

For Each varItem In Me!List2.ItemSelected
    strFind = srtFind & "," & Me!List2.ItemData(varItem)
Next varItem
If Len(strFind) > 0 Then
    strFind = Right(strFind, Len(strFind) - 1)
    Filter = "[Bid Amount] In (" & strFind & ")"
    FilterOn = True
End If

Me!NameOfSubformControl1.Form.Filter = Filter
Me!NameOfSubformControl2.Form.Filter = Filter
Me!NameOfSubformControl1.Form.FilterOn = FilterOn
Me!NameOfSubformControl2.Form.FilterOn = FilterOn
```

Comment: Private Sub Find_Click()
Dim varItem     As Variant
Dim strFind     As String
Dim Filter      As String
Dim FilterOn    As Boolean

For Each varItem In Me.List2.ItemsSelected
    strFind = srtFind & "," & Me.List2.ItemData(varItem)
Next varItem
If Len(strFind) > 0 Then
    strFind = Right(strFind, Len(strFind) - 1)
    Filter = "[Bid Amount] In (" & strFind & ")"
    FilterOn = True
End If

Me.Min.Form.Filter = "Filter"
Me.Avg.Form.Filter = "Filter"
Me.Min.Form.FilterOn = True
Me.Avg.Form.FilterOn = True
End Sub

Comment: Try with `Me!Min.Form.Filter` and double-check `strFilter` and your recordsources of the subforms.